# Building BLAS, ATLAS and LAPACK without OpenMP support

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, lapack, blas, atlas

I have been using some prebuilt linear algebra libraries that use OpenMP to parallelize their execution.

Right now I am working in a project with OpenMP to parallelize some tasks. So I set the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS.

Some threads make use of BLAS and LAPACK linear algebra routines. These libraries are also parallel and take a look at the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS to see the number of threads that they have to use.

For requirements of my project. I need to avoid this nested parallelization by making use of a non parallel BLAS and LAPACK implementation.

What is the best library and how can it be built?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use OpenBLAS. This library includes its one version of LAPACK routines and is quite flexible with respect to threading.

The number of threads can be defined either at [compile time](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/blob/develop/GotoBLAS_02QuickInstall.txt):

```
$shell> make USE_THREAD=0
```

or using explicit [environment variable](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS#set-the-number-of-threads-with-environment-variables):

```
export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4
```

or using library [API](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS#set-the-number-of-threads-on-runtime) at runtime:

```
void openblas_set_num_threads(int num_threads);
```

Comment: One question, if I use: make USE_THREAD=1 and after that in I use export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4. How many threads there will be? Because I need a BLAS implementation that always use 1 thread no matter what environment variables are defined.

Comment: If threading is deactivated at compile time, it cannot be reactivated at runtime

Comment: Thank you very much